# Unable to update the font-family and its size on GitHub using Chrome/Brave

Tags: github, fonts

I am accessing GitHub via Chrome/Brave. To change the family and size of the fonts of the code on GitHub I am using **Refined GitHub** chrome extension. The article I followed is: [Customize GitHub's code font](https://dev.to/supercilex/customize-github-s-code-font-2po0)

All was going well, but now the font are rendered in the default GitHub style instead of the one I was using.

I am still able to render my expected font-style in this window:
[image]

But when I navigate to one of the files containing the source code, I get this:
[image]

Also, I tried to tweak the CSS stored in Refined GitHub extension, but it didn't work.

How do I start rendering my font style again using Refined GitHub?